# php streaming wav in firefox vs chrome

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, firefox, audio

I have a hidden audio element in a page, and i'm setting the source dynamically. im setting it as a php page with a GET request that finds the file based on the GET parameter.

However, the audio element is taking the wav file just fine in Chrome but not in firefox. Here is the query and html

```
    <html>
<audio id = "play_wav" controls>
<span id = "set_source">set source</span>

<script>
$('#set_source').on('click', function(){
    $('#play_wav').attr('src', 'get_wav.php?fname=playme.wav');
    document.getElementById('play_wav').play();
});

</script>

</html>
```

and here's get_wav.php

```
if(isset($_GET['fname])){
    $fname = $_GET['fname'];
    readfile($fname);
}
```

So this is working to play streaming audio in chrome but not in firefox. The source is still being set it's just not loading. Any suggestions?

Comment: *sidenote* your open to attack with your current php code, for example `get_wav.php?fname=index.php` will echo out the source of the index.php file.

Comment: *another sidenote* you have a syntax error in `get_waw.php` near `isset()`.

Comment: i'm aware of that the paramater is actually and alias in a database. thank you though. this is just to demonstrate one problem

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should not store the audio files in the same directory as your php files because its easy to protect from someone loading your PHP files by using the [basename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function to isolate the filename else you **must** make further checks its not a php or system file path thats been passed to the `$_GET['fname']` parameter, you should also put a .htaccess in the media folder with `deny from all` in it, this will stop direct access and if you want to be able to stream with seek-able functionality then you need to handle the HTTP_RANGE headers.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['fname'])){
    $file_name = './wav_files/'.basename($_GET['fname']);
    stream($file_name, 'audio/wav');
}

/**
 * Streamable file handler
 *
 * @param String $file_location
 * @param Header|String $content_type
 * @return content
 */
function stream($file, $content_type = 'application/octet-stream') {

    // Make sure the files exists
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    }

    // Get file size
    $filesize = sprintf("%u", filesize($file));

    // Handle 'Range' header
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])){
        $range = $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'];
    }elseif($apache = apache_request_headers()){
        $headers = array();
        foreach ($apache as $header => $val){
            $headers[strtolower($header)] = $val;
        }
        if(isset($headers['range'])){
            $range = $headers['range'];
        }
        else $range = FALSE;
    } else $range = FALSE;

    //Is range
    if($range){
        $partial = true;
        list($param, $range) = explode('=',$range);
        // Bad request - range unit is not 'bytes'
        if(strtolower(trim($param)) != 'bytes'){
            header("HTTP/1.1 400 Invalid Request");
            exit;
        }
        // Get range values
        $range = explode(',',$range);
        $range = explode('-',$range[0]);
        // Deal with range values
        if ($range[0] === ''){
            $end = $filesize - 1;
            $start = $end - intval($range[0]);
        } else if ($range[1] === '') {
            $start = intval($range[0]);
            $end = $filesize - 1;
        }else{
            // Both numbers present, return specific range
            $start = intval($range[0]);
            $end = intval($range[1]);
            if ($end >= $filesize || (!$start && (!$end || $end == ($filesize - 1)))) $partial = false;
        }
        $length = $end - $start + 1;
    }
    // No range requested
    else {
        $partial = false;
        $length = $filesize;
    }

    // Send standard headers
    header("Content-Type: $content_type");
    header("Content-Length: $length");
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

    // send extra headers for range handling...
    if ($partial) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$filesize");
        if (!$fp = fopen($file, 'rb')) { // Error out if we can't read the file
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            exit;
        }
        if ($start) fseek($fp,$start);
        while($length){
            set_time_limit(0);
            $read = ($length > 8192) ? 8192 : $length;
            $length -= $read;
            print(fread($fp,$read));
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
    //just send the whole file
    else readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: I just tried this, couldnt get it to work for firefox or chrome. no errors in apache log

Comment: I just got it to work by adding header('Content-type:audio/wav) and firefox had no problem with it